# SWIG cross platform

Tags: python, windows, macos, swig

My application is using SWIG to communicate between c++ and python on windows.

suppose if my interface is "example.h"

swig is generating example.py, example_wrap.cxx

```
  /* File : example.i */
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_wstring.i"
%include "example.h"
```

I am porting my application to MAC. Do i need to generate example.py, example_wrap.cxx on mac? or can i use already generated files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWIG generates the same code regardless of the platform it is executed on.

If any parts of that code are OS/Compiler/etc.-specific (e.g. calling conventions on Windows for C#), this is handled by conditional compilation for C++ resp. similar techniques in the target language.